# Python beautifulsoup: Removing specific element in element

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a set of html files. I need remove a links from "ul/li" segment but other links ands "ul/li" segments must stay.

I am using BS for this.

```
<p>
  <a href="link" class="story body__link">link</a>
 </p>

<ul class="story-body__unordered-list">
  <li class="story-body__list-item">
    <a href="link" class="story-body__link">link</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="story-body__unordered-list">
  <li class="story-body__list-item">
    text
  </li>
</ul>
```

I am using python BS for this task. And I managed to make this task by this code, but its not perfect. My question is there any better and cleaner solution for this?

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')


for i in soup.find_all('li', attrs={"story-body__list-item"}):
    x = str(i.next_element)
    if x.startswith( '<a' ) == True:
        i.decompose()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this and see if it works on your actual code:

```
for link in soup.select("li.story-body__list-item > a"):   
     link.parent.decompose()
```

Or alternatively:

```
for link.parent in soup.select("li.story-body__list-item > a"):    
     link.decompose()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that by getting your links thanks to their class name.

```
for i in soup.findAll("a", {"class": "story-body__link"}):
    ...
```

You can use lists too: soup.find_all("a", ["stylelistrowone", "stylelistrowtwo"])